# Bigcommerce is allowing to select combination of options for which there is no SKU present

Tags: api, bigcommerce, ruby-on-rails-5.1

I have a product 'Shirt' which is having two variants:

```
 1. color = blue and size = L
 2. color = Red and Size = M
```

When I am adding this product on bigcommerce using v3 API and looking at this product on store I am able to select combination of options `color = Red and Size = L`. Where as in actual there is no such variant present for this product with such combination of options. How can I restrict user from selecting the combination of options for which there is no SKU present on bigcommerce?

Answer (score 0):

This is a better question for BigCommerce support, but I'll discuss some reasons this can happen.

When you create a SKU, that is all you are doing. You are creating an arbitrary string for stock keeping units. For BigCommerce to limit the purchase of items, you also have to use a stock setting on the product called "track inventory by product" or "track inventory by options" as seen in this [support article](https://support.bigcommerce.com/articles/Public/Managing-Inventory/).

If you don't have track inventory by options enabled, then any combination of the options is possible because it only cares about the stock of the parent product if it is even tracking that.

Comment: Actually I am passing "inventory_tracking" : "variant" in body parameter of API while creating products. But if in the inventory settings of bigcommerce store "When an option is out of stock"  is set to "don't do anything" then it is allowing user to select any combination of options while placing order. I can't force my each and every user to change their inventory settings and also there is no such API which will change the inventory settings. Thus if I am passing "inventory_tracking" : "variant" then it should automatically hide options which are not available.